# How can i recover the Factory reset password

Tags: router, password-recovery

I know my password and can even get to my router what I want to know, is there any way to recover the Factory reset password. It is not attached to my router and i need to reset the router back to factory setting so can insert it into another network as an extension

Comment: What router are you using?

Comment: Have you google'd "[router brand + model] default password" ?

Comment: Have you checked the router documentation?  The Netgear web site?  Netgear tech support?

Answer (score 1):

Most consumer routers have a lightweight web server running on either port 80 or 443 (HTTP and HTTPS, respectively) that allows you to not only change settings on the router, but also reset to factory defaults, assuming you haven't flashed custom firmware on the router.

Look for a page or tab labeled "Administration" or "Advanced" after logging into the router. Odds are you'll find the setting you're looking for buried somewhere on one of those pages.

Also worth pointing out is that if you don't know what the factory default password is, resetting the router back to factory defaults won't help you. It will reset **everything** back to factory defaults, including the current router password. If you don't know it already, you won't be able to log in to the router after resetting it.

A better solution would be to check http://www.routerpasswords.com for the default password instead.